# How to push items off of asyncio.PriorityQueue when it is at maxsize and I put() new items?

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio, priority-queue

I have an `asyncio.PriorityQueue` that I am using as the URL queue for a web crawler, with the lowest scored URLs being the first removed from the queue when I call `url_queue.get()`. When the queue reaches `maxsize` items, the default behavior is to block on calls to `url_queue.put()`, until a call to `get()` removes an item from the queue to make space.

What I would like to do is to never block, but instead push off the queue item with the highest score (or least an item with one of the highest scores), whenever I attempt to `put()` an item that has a lower score. Is there a way to automatically remove items from the bottom of the heap this way in `asyncio.PriorityQueue`? If not, is there an alternative priority queue / heap implementation that works with asyncio, which would enable me to do this? Or some other data structure / technique that would enable me to have some kind of non-blocking, prioritized queue with a maximum size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically remove items from the bottom of the heap this way in `asyncio.PriorityQueue`?

Not by default, but it should be straightforward to inherit from `asyncio.PriorityQueue` and just implement the desired behavior. Unlike multi-threaded queue implementations, the asyncio queue runs in a single thread and therefore does not need to worry about synchronization issues.

A possible issue with performance is that `PriorityQueue` is not designed as a double-ended queue, so it uses a heap to store items. A heap is either *min* or *max*, but not both; Python's `heapq` module implements a min-heap, but you can easily simulate a max-heap by multiplying priorities by -1. In a min-heap one can access and pop the smallest item in logarithmic time, but not the largest one, and in a max-heap it's the other way around. To efficiently manipulate both the smallest and the largest item, you'll need to inherit from `asyncio.Queue` and use a different data structure to store items, such as a [sorted list](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/introduction.html).

For example (untested):

```
class DroppingPriorityQueue(asyncio.Queue):
    def _init(self, maxsize):
        # called by asyncio.Queue.__init__
        self._queue = sortedcontainers.SortedList()

    def _put(self, item):
        # called by asyncio.Queue.put_nowait
        self._queue.add(item)

    def _get(self):
        # called by asyncio.Queue.get_nowait
        # pop the first (most important) item off the queue
        return self._queue.pop(0)

    def __drop(self):
        # drop the last (least important) item from the queue
        self._queue.pop()
        # no consumer will get a chance to process this item, so
        # we must decrement the unfinished count ourselves
        self.task_done()

    def put_nowait(self, item):
        if self.full():
            self.__drop()
        super().put_nowait(item)

    async def put(self, item):
        # Queue.put blocks when full, so we must override it.
        # Since our put_nowait never raises QueueFull, we can just
        # call it directly
        self.put_nowait(item)
```

The class implements two distinct concerns:

- It overrides the `_get`, `_put`, and `_init` protected methods to use a [`SortedList`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) as the underlying storage. Although undocumented, these methods are used for building customized queues such as [`PriorityQueue`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d8080c01195cc9a19af752bfa04d98824dd9fb15/Lib/asyncio/queues.py#L219) and [`LifoQueue`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d8080c01195cc9a19af752bfa04d98824dd9fb15/Lib/asyncio/queues.py#L235) and have been in place for decades, first in the `Queue` module (`queue` in Python 3) and later in `asyncio.queue`.
- It overrides the `put` and `put_nowait` public methods to implement the drop-when-full semantics.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about writing a wrapper around PriorityQueue that manually removes items when needed, but I couldn't figure out how to access anything other than top of heap. The problem with your suggested solution is that it removes the item with the *lowest* score (i.e. the highest priority item). The scores used to sort in the queue represent URL priority/relevance, and thus by calling `self.get_nowait()`, I would be removing the *most* relevant URL. I want to remove the *least* relevant or lowest priority URLs from the queue, when URLs with a higher relevance score are added.

Comment: @J.Taylor Ouch, you're right. There are actually two questions here: how to customize asyncio Queue to drop items instead of waiting when the queue is full, and how to pop the item off the opposite side of the heap. My answer answers the first question correctly, but it doesn't cover the second one at all. Looking at the heap implementation/theory, it might not be possible at all (in logarithmic time) using a heap.

Comment: I'm looking at the source code for cpython's `heapq` module (which `PriorityQueue` is based on internally), and the heap is stored as a list there. The leftmost list item q[0] is the min heap item (top of the heap). But I don't think there is any guarantee that the rightmost list item q[-1] is *always* the max heap item. But even if q[-1] is any leaf (not necessarily *the* lowest score, but one of them), it would be good enough for my purposes. I would have to muck in internals of heapq, but it might work ... going to experiment with that and write an answer up if nobody has a better solution.

Comment: Ran out of chars above ... but what I'm saying is that if q[-1] is any leaf item (possibly the max), I could just do q.pop() to toss the element to make space in the queue. However, I am not familiar enough with asyncio or heapq to know if modifying this internal/private list like this would break something either in the queue itself, or in the async code consuming from / pushing to the queue...

Comment: @J.Taylor I wouldn't recommend popping `q[-1]` before carefully checking that it doesn't break heap invariants. As far as `asyncio.Queue` is concerned, I'm pretty sure it doesn't care what you do to `self._queue`, since it is used as a base for customized queues. I've now amended the answer to show how to achieve popping from two sides using the excellent `sortedcontainers` third-party module.

Comment: @J.Taylor According to [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-element-in-min-heap/), the fastest way to find the max element in a min heap requires searching through n/2 nodes, so it's still O(n). It seems that heap is simply not the right data structure for a double ended priority queue. There is the [min-max heap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap), but not in the stdlib. I would either accept the O(n) removal time or go with the `sortedcontainers` as shown in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write out that example! I had never heard of sortedcontainers, which looks perfect for this (and useful to know about in general). The O(n) removal time for the heap won't suffice, because I need adding to the queue to be a fast operation. Your example looks like it will work, and explains what I was struggling to understand (how to override queue methods properly, and maintain sorting while also being able to pop from both ends). I am going to implement it today in my application, and if it works out I'll come back and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Actually, a min-max heap is not difficult to implement, and it should perform better than the sorted containers.

Comment: @JimMischel Sure, implementing one's own min-max heap is always an option. But if my task were to implement a priority queue, I'd prefer re-using a field-tested and debugged module, which is also useful for other things. Also, beating sortedcontainers may not be as easy as it seems, as quite some [thought](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7z2Ki44Vs4E) has entered into making them efficient.